# Error *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated C++

Tags: c#, c++

El ejercicio es facil, generar una matriz 4x20 (simulando una planilla de 20 alumnos y 4 materias) que se carguen con numeros aleatorios. El problema es que al finalizar el codigo me sale el error *** stack smashing detected *** Fragmento del codigo que creo que contiene el error abajo.

```
for (j = 0 ; j < 20; j++){
    sumpers=0;
  for (k = 0 ; k < 4; k++){
  sumpers = sumpers + mat[j][k];
}
float prompers = float (sumpers) / 4;
  cout << "el promedio personal del alumno " << j << " es " <<prompers<<" \n";
  if (prompers>may){
      may=prompers;
  }
}
cout<<"El mejor alumno tiene promedio "<<may<<"\n";
```

Por otro lado, que no estoy encontrando manera de plantear, es que el codigo debe encontrar la ubicacion y mostrar solo su posicion de columna del alumno con mejor promedio.
Este es la primera parte del codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int j, k, mat[4][20], sumpers=0, may=0;
float prompers=0;
srand(time(NULL));
for (j=0 ; j<20 ; j++){
    for (k=0 ; k<4 ; k++){
        mat[j][k]=0 + rand() % (6-0);
        cout<<mat[j][k]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"<--alumno "<<j;
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Duplicaste la pregunta, por favor deja solo una publicación de las 2, por otro lado ¿C# o C++?

Comment: Entiendo que el bucle exterior ha de ir desde 0 a 4 y el interior desde 0 a 20

Comment: BetaM, sería C++, por otro lado, me fijé que la pregunta fue duplicada, no estoy encontrando la manera de eliminar la otra publicación por que no la estoy encontrando.